# Simple BloomFilter Class

Tags: java, cache, bloom-filter

We have some [`BloomFilter`s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) (like a `java.util.set` without deletion) and we store them in [ehcache](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3) (you can think it's as a `java.util.Map`):

For example, `Constant.BLOOM_FILTER_CACHE` ehcache contains:

```
key   value
aaa   bloomfilter (of name aaa)
bbb   bloomfilter (of name bbb)
ccc   bloomfilter (of name ccc)
```

If we call `localCacheManager.get(Constant.BLOOM_FILTER_CACHE, aaa)`, it will return a `bloomfilter` (of name aaa) or `Null` (if not initialized).

If we call `localCacheManager.put(Constant.BLOOM_FILTER_CACHE, aaa, new BloomFilter(100, 0.001))`, it will put a bloomfilte to cache entry `aaa`.

If we want to add `data1` into `BloomFilter` of name `aaa`, then we may call `add(aaa, data1)` and if we want to know if `aaa` `BloomFilter` contains `data1`, we should call `contains(aaa, data1)` (in that case, it will return `true`).

If we want to look up or add, we should check the `bloomfilter` is initialized or not.

```
package com.xxx.utils.bloomfilter;

import com.clearspring.analytics.stream.membership.BloomFilter;
import com.xxx.utils.cache.ehcache.LocalCacheManager;
import com.xxx.utils.common.Constant;

public class BloomFilterInCache {
  private int bloomFilterElementSize;
  private double bloomFilterErrorRate;
  private LocalCacheManager localCacheManager;

  public BloomFilterInCache(int bloomFilterElementSize,
      double bloomFilterErrorRate, LocalCacheManager localCacheManager) {
    this.bloomFilterElementSize = bloomFilterElementSize;
    this.bloomFilterErrorRate = bloomFilterErrorRate;
    this.localCacheManager = localCacheManager;
  }

  private boolean isBloomFilterExistsByName(String name)
  {
    BloomFilter bf = (BloomFilter) localCacheManager.get(Constant.BLOOM_FILTER_CACHE, name);
    if (bf == null)
      return false;
    return true;
  }

  private void newBloomFilter(String name)
  {
    BloomFilter bf = new BloomFilter(bloomFilterElementSize, bloomFilterErrorRate);
    localCacheManager.put(Constant.BLOOM_FILTER_CACHE, name, bf);
  }

  private void NotExistsThenPut(String name)
  {
    if (!isBloomFilterExistsByName(name))
    {
      newBloomFilter(name);
    }
  }

  public boolean contains(String name, String key)
  {
    NotExistsThenPut(name);
    BloomFilter bf = (BloomFilter) localCacheManager.get(Constant.BLOOM_FILTER_CACHE, name);
    return bf.isPresent(key);
  }

  public void add(String name, String key)
  {
    NotExistsThenPut(name);
    BloomFilter bf = (BloomFilter) localCacheManager.get(Constant.BLOOM_FILTER_CACHE, name);
    bf.add(key);
  }
}
```

Are there any flaws in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private boolean isBloomFilterExistsByName(String name)
{
```

The brace belong on the previous line.

```
isBloomFilterExistsByName(String name)
```

`is...Exists` sounds strange.

```
 private void newBloomFilter(String name)
```

From the name, I'd expect this method to return a new Bloom Filter instead of putting it somewhere.

```
 private void NotExistsThenPut(String name)
```

Java method names starts with lowercase. A better name would be `putIfNotExists`.

I'd actually prefer a method like `getOrCreate`.

```
public boolean contains(String name, String key)
```

`contains` and `isPresent` are wrong names for this. A Bloom Filter is like a `Set`, but an undependable one. A much better name is `mayContain`.

This method is an invitation to inefficiency. Imagine a tight loop calling it. On every iteration you look up the Bloom Filter twice (once to make sure that it exists and once to use it). This may easily dominate the cost of the filter's `isPresent` operation.

I'd suggest to provide methods allowing to use it like

```
 bloomFilterInCache.getOrCreate("name").mayContain("element");
```

which allows efficiency via "extract local variable".

```
 public void add(String name, String key)
```

Again, an invitation to inefficiency.